# DotNetNuke - Allowing users to save their credentials in their browser

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

The default behavior of a DNN installation is to prevent users from saving their account credentials in their browser.

I believe this is done by changing the ID of the credential input controls on the login page(s), but I am not sure.

Is there a setting or common method for fixing this so that users can save their credentials?

**Edit:** I'm not talking about the separate issue of whether a user's session is "remembered" by clicking "remember me". I'm just referring to enabling web browsers' login/pw storage. It can't be too horrible to enable if Amazon allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually done by setting an `autocomplete=off` attribute on the textbox.  I don't believe that this is exposed through a setting (i.e. the only way to change it is to change the control that your authentication provider uses, which is a fairly big undertaking).

Comment: I'll see if I can locate this. It's really unfortunate that the DNN corp decided to leave a dysfunctional (or at least misleading) checkbox in the login control that launches with DNN (Remember my info...)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After reading further on this, it seems this solution is less secure than the one provided [here](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1784/a-new-solution-to-an-old-problem.aspx).

If you are talking about the issue where remember me doesn't work, you just need to make a simple change to your web.config file. Just increase the value of the timeout setting in the authentication -> forms section it's also a good idea to add slidingExpiration="true"

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".DOTNETNUKE" protection="All" timeout="10080" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Hi. My question may have been a bit ambiguous (I will clear it up some). I just want the browser to remember the username and password credentials. Something is keeping the browsers from remembering credentials in DNN 5.4 - 5.6 (at least).

Comment: This page - http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2012/05/04/dotnetnuke-login-and-auto-complete---how-to-cope.aspx, might have the answer you are looking for?